# Play 2.0.4 Problems updating a class that uses @EmbeddedId

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

I’ve recently come across a problem with a class that has an embedded id.  Whenever I want to update an existing entry in the database, I get the error “`java.lang.RuntimeException: No @javax.persistence.Id field found in class`”. I only get this error, when I use `update()` or `save()` on an object that's already an exciting db entry. Using `save()` to insert a new entry, works without a problem and so does deleting an existing entry with `delete()`.

Someone else posted a question about this problem in the Play Framework Google Group, but sadly it never got answered. So I thought I'd try asking for help here.

Here's how my code basically looks:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "files_location")
public class FilesLocation extends Model {

    @EmbeddedId
    public FilesLocationPK ids;

    @Column(name="status")
    public Character status; 

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("fileId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "file_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public File file;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("locationId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "location_id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Location location;

}



@Embeddable
public class FilesLocationPK {

    @Column(name="file_id")
    public Integer fileId;

    @Column(name="location_id")
    public Integer locationId;
    ...
}
```

The Error looks like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No @javax.persistence.Id field found in class [class models.FilesLocation]
    at play.db.ebean.Model._idAccessors(Model.java:39)
    at play.db.ebean.Model._getId(Model.java:52)
    at play.db.ebean.Model.hashCode(Model.java:183)
    at java.lang.Object.toString(Object.java:219)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.Format.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(Unknown Source)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.core.Message.msg(Message.java:39)
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the @Id annotation on the key columns in your PK class.

Ebean is going to want to locate a sequence to use to generate these, as well.

Comment: I finally got around to trying this out, but when I did I ended up getting this error `[IllegalArgumentException: (was java.lang.NullPointerException) (through reference chain: model.Tag["files"]->com.avaje.ebean.common.BeanList[0]->model.File["location"])]`. It would seem that FileLocation isn't properly being loaded.